# Invest, utilize or fund?

Tags: word-choice

Which word out of the above three suits this sentence?
"If I got such amount of money, I would ______ it for the project of....."

Comment: I think they are all grammatically correct, it's just they have slightly different meanings. Also rather than will, I'd use would.

Comment: yeah, that was a mistake.. thanks.......
corrected

Comment: "Utilize it for...", "invest it in...", "use it to fund the project".

Comment: so much $ ... donate

Answer (score 1):

Use **invest** if there is an expected return—that is, if the project is likely to make the speaker money: "If I got such an amount of money, I would invest it in the project so that it might expand into new markets and bring in even greater profits."

Use **utilize** and **fund** if the money will be put into the project with no expectation of return: "I would utilize the money for the project in order to construct an orphanage in Africa" or "I would use the money to fund the project in order to construct an orphanage in Africa." The first sentence is more compact and will likely flow better in the text.

If the case is to specifically add money to an ongoing project which will presumably continue after this particular source of revenue runs out, then I would prefer **fund**: "I will use the money to fund the African Orphanage Association in its mission to build orphanages in Africa."